# Is there a way to filter data in aes 256 gcm encrypted database?

Tags: mysql, node.js, search, encryption, mariadb

I have a database with sensitive information encrypted with aes 256 gcm. But I have to filter it before sending data to the frontend. Currently, I get all the data and filter it in the application. It works fine now. But I think that it might be a problem in the future when the database gets a lot bigger and my current approach to this problem will be slow and not optimal. But I don't know about a way to search in encrypted rows which are encrypted in the application.

Example:

| id | email(not encrypted) | firstname(encrypted) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | qwerty@qwerty.com | DPTR0zNqreWoZUwajRcJJtMlgji7TrSuzcuPbDfIsqvc6g= |
| 2 | qwerty@qwerty1.com | DCAvCh1JewOIJl3EQprmgnfy9VT5r6BGFGuyqkBpicNM |

If the user's 1 name is Patrick and the user's 2 name is Joe how do I get all users using SQL query with a name that starts with Pat...

Comment: Do you use the same key for each of the rows? how the IV's are generated? Searchable encryption can be done, however, you should well define your schema and queries so that one can really help you. The answer suggests you to send the key to the database server. Is this a security risk for you? If not, why encryption at all?

Comment: I don't use same key for each of the rows. IV is generated using node.js crypto function crypto.randomBytes(12).

Comment: If you don't use the same key, then you need to decrypt all rows to see that one matches. Any specific reason not to use AES-GCM-SIV? SIV protects use from IV reuse problem of GCM mode that inherited from the internal CTR mode.

Answer (score 1):

> SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE AES_DECRYPT(firstname,[KEY])='Pat%'

This should do the trick, it decrypts every name and compares it with the given string.
Keep in mind that you are sending the encryption key over the connection, if the sql server is on the same Machine as the Client it is safe, otherwise you could use f.e. SSL/TLS

Comment: Is this capable of decrypting 256bit cipher with gcm mode ? Also, I forgot to mention that data is encrypted with multiple keys. We change the secret key every month.

Comment: Well, i dont know how you encrypt the data exactly but i guess using multiple AES_DECRYPTS would help.  Furthermore gcm mode is as far as i know only for performance so same input same output but i dont really know a lot about it.